# Array in Gui to Increment

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface

Hi i have a trouble in my program because i need to set an array for easy way of incrementing it because it is sales so i declare of my array like this  iam not yet done of my program this is my program so far .

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;




public class We extends JFrame
{

    public static JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    public static String totallist,addprod;
    public static int grandtotal,ve,xxx,z,x,adding,pay,totalp,totalc,payment;
    public static JTextField in = new JTextField(z);
    public static JTextField ki = new JTextField(15);    
    public static double disc,totalbayad,sukli;
    public static int benta[] = new int [11];
    public static String prod[] = new String[11];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        We frameTabel = new We();


        prod[1] = "Palmolive";
        prod[2] = "Egg";
        prod[3] = "Milo";
        prod[4] = "Noodles";
        prod[5] = "PancitCanton";
        prod[6] = "CornBeef";
        prod[7] = "LigoSardines";
        prod[8] = "CokeSakto";
        prod[9] = "RcBig";
        prod[10] = "GibsonLespaulGuitar";

        benta[1] = 6;
        benta[2] = 5;
        benta[3] = 6;
        benta[4] = 9;
        benta[5] = 10;
        benta[6] = 25;
        benta[7] = 16;
        benta[8] = 6;
        benta[9] = 16;
        benta[10] = 14000;


    }


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Customer");
        JFrame prodcho = new JFrame("Unofficial receipt");
        JFrame want = new JFrame("Buy AGain");
        JFrame ftinda = new JFrame("Item && Prices");
        JButton blogin = new JButton("Login");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField txuser = new JTextField(15);
        JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(15);
        JLabel lab = new JLabel("Username :");
        JLabel pas = new JLabel("Password :");
        JLabel cos;
        //JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton y1;
        JButton y2;

    We()
        {
            super("Enter Your Account !");
            setSize(300,200);
            setLocation(500,280);
            panel.setLayout (null);


            txuser.setBounds(90,30,150,20);
            pass.setBounds(90,65,150,20);
            blogin.setBounds(110,100,80,20);
            lab.setBounds(15,28,150,20);
            pas.setBounds(15,63,150,20);

            panel.add(lab);
            panel.add(pas);
            panel.add(blogin);
            panel.add(txuser);
            panel.add(pass);

            getContentPane().add(panel);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
            actionlogin();

        }

            public void actionlogin()
        {
            blogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
             {
                String puname = txuser.getText();
                String ppaswd = pass.getText();
                if(puname.equals("vincent") && ppaswd.equals("puge"))
            {

                setVisible(false);
                JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setSize(300,200);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout());

                    cos = new JLabel("Do you have a Customer ?");
                    y1 = new JButton("Yes");
                    y2 = new JButton("No");


                        panel1.setLayout(null);
                        cos.setBounds(70,30,150,20);
                        y1.setBounds(80,65,150,20);
                        y2.setBounds(140,65,150,20);
                        y1.setSize(55,30);
                        y2.setSize(55,30);
                        panel1.add(y1);
                        panel1.add(y2);
                        panel1.add(cos);
                        frame.add(panel1);




                   y1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                   {
                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                       {
                           Object source = ae.getSource();

                           if(source == y1)
                           {
                               frame.setVisible(false);
                               //--------------------------------------
                               int boundsStart=10;
                               panel.l2.add(new JLabel("-Product-").setBounds(20,boundsStart,150,20));
                               boundsStart+=20;

                               for (int i=1; i<11; i++)
                               {
                                    panel2.add(new JLabel(i+"."+prod[i]).setBounds(20,boundsStart,150,20));
                                    boundsStart+=20;
                               }

                               boundsStart = 30; //reset bounds counter

                               for (int i=1; i<11; i++)
                               {
                                    panel2.add(new JLabel(""+benta[i]).setBounds(20,boundsStart,150,20));
                                    boundsStart+=20;
                               }
                               //You could then change the other JLabels that came after this point in the same way I just did
                               //price,ent,law, and qx

                               //--------------------------------------

                               JLabel vince = new JLabel("-Product-");
                               JLabel l1 = new JLabel("1."+prod[1]);
                               JLabel l2 = new JLabel("2."+prod[2]);
                               JLabel l3 = new JLabel("3."+prod[3]);
                               JLabel l4 = new JLabel("4."+prod[4]);
                               JLabel l5 = new JLabel("5."+prod[5]);
                               JLabel l6 = new JLabel("6."+prod[6]);
                               JLabel l7 = new JLabel("7."+prod[7]);
                               JLabel l8 = new JLabel("8."+prod[8]);
                               JLabel l9 = new JLabel("9."+prod[9]);
                               JLabel l10 = new JLabel("10."+prod[10]);
                               JLabel p1 = new JLabel(""+benta[1]);
                               JLabel p2 = new JLabel(""+benta[2]);
                               JLabel p3 = new JLabel(""+benta[3]);
                               JLabel p4 = new JLabel(""+benta[4]);
                               JLabel p5 = new JLabel(""+benta[5]);
                               JLabel p6 = new JLabel(""+benta[6]);
                               JLabel p7 = new JLabel(""+benta[7]);
                               JLabel p8 = new JLabel(""+benta[8]);
                               JLabel p9 = new JLabel(""+benta[9]);
                               JLabel p10 = new JLabel(""+benta[10]);
                               JLabel price = new JLabel("-Price-");

                               JButton ent = new JButton("Enter");
                               JLabel law = new JLabel("Enter No. of Product");
                               JLabel qx = new JLabel("Enter Quantity");




                               ftinda.setVisible(true);
                               ftinda.setSize(350,350);
                               ftinda.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                               ftinda.setLayout(new GridLayout());

                               panel2.setLayout(null);
                               vince.setBounds(20,10,150,20);
                               l1.setBounds(20,30,150,20);
                               l2.setBounds(20,50,150,20);
                               l3.setBounds(20,70,150,20);
                               l4.setBounds(20,90,150,20);
                               l5.setBounds(20,110,150,20);
                               l6.setBounds(20,130,150,20);
                               l7.setBounds(20,150,150,20);
                               l8.setBounds(20,170,150,20);
                               l9.setBounds(20,190,150,20);
                               l10.setBounds(20,210,150,20);
                               p1.setBounds(230,30,150,20);
                               p2.setBounds(230,50,150,20);
                               p3.setBounds(230,70,150,20);
                               p4.setBounds(230,90,150,20);
                               p5.setBounds(230,110,150,20);
                               p6.setBounds(230,130,150,20);
                               p7.setBounds(230,150,150,20);
                               p8.setBounds(230,170,150,20);
                               p9.setBounds(230,190,150,20);
                               p10.setBounds(230,210,150,20);
                               price.setBounds(225,10,150,20);
                               in.setBounds(150,250,150,20);
                               law.setBounds(20,253,150,20);
                               qx.setBounds(20,280,150,20);
                               ki.setBounds(150,280,150,20);
                               ent.setBounds(220,250,150,20);
                               in.setSize(42,20);
                               ki.setSize(42,20);
                               ent.setSize(65,50);




                               panel2.add(vince);
                               panel2.add(l1);
                               panel2.add(l2);
                               panel2.add(l3);
                               panel2.add(l4);
                               panel2.add(l5);
                               panel2.add(l6);
                               panel2.add(l7);
                               panel2.add(l8);
                               panel2.add(l9);
                               panel2.add(l10);
                               panel2.add(p1);
                               panel2.add(p2);
                               panel2.add(p3);
                               panel2.add(p4);
                               panel2.add(p5);
                               panel2.add(p6);
                               panel2.add(p7);
                               panel2.add(p8);
                               panel2.add(p9);
                               panel2.add(p10);
                               panel2.add(price);
                               panel2.add(in);
                               panel2.add(law);
                               panel2.add(ent);
                               panel2.add(qx);
                               panel2.add(ki);                              
                               ftinda.add(panel2);

                               ent.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                               {
                                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                                   {


                                      ftinda.setVisible(false);
                                      JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
                                      JLabel cos1 = new JLabel("Do you want to buy more ?");
                                      JButton yy = new JButton("Yes");
                                      JButton  nn = new JButton("No");


                                      panel3.setLayout(null);
                                      cos1.setBounds(70,30,150,20);
                                      yy.setBounds(80,65,150,20);
                                      nn.setBounds(140,65,150,20);
                                      yy.setSize(55,30);
                                      nn.setSize(55,30);
                                      panel3.add(cos1);
                                      panel3.add(yy);
                                      panel3.add(nn);

                                      want.add(panel3);

                                      want.setVisible(true);
                                      want.setSize(300,200);
                                      want.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                                      want.setLayout(new GridLayout());


                                      addprod = prod[];
                                      adding = benta[];
                                      totalp = 
                                      totalc = totalp;
                                      totallist = totallist + addprod +"" +x+ "pcs = "+totalc+"pesos";


                                      nn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                                      {
                                          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ea)
                                          {
                                              Object source1 = ea.getSource();
                                              {
                                                  if(source1 == nn)
                                                  {

                                                      JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();




                                                      panel4.setLayout(null);
                                                      prodcho.setVisible(true);
                                                      prodcho.setSize(300,200);
                                                      prodcho.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                                                      prodcho.setLayout(new GridLayout());

                                                      prodcho.add(panel4);
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }
                                      });

                                   }
                               });

                           }
                       }
                   });


            }
            else
                {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Password / Username");
                    txuser.setText("");
                    pass.setText("");
                    txuser.requestFocus();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I advise you to read about [loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: Read about [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: not the loop is the problem . ill got sales in my java program but i used it into JOption so ill easy connect the array because of int can put inside t he benta[z]; like that but not does the same as the GUi program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PeterMmm stated arrayLists should be able to solve your predicament. ArrayLists allow you to make an array of any type very easily and has a very nice interface such as

```
mylist.add(element)
```

Maroun Maroun also made a valid point that you can approach this much more nicely using a loop so that you can avoid the large amount of repitition in your code, but its not necessary to do so if you are happy with it.

Hopefully the following sample of using ArrayList can help you:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/05/example-of-arraylist-in-java-tutorial.html

And if you want more information about arraylist here is the docs:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

My last tip, while looking at your code is to add an actionListener to your button, as currently it does nothing ;)

```
ent.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
    {
        //..do stuff here or call a function to do stuff :)
    }
});
```

Comment: i am using do while loop to this program but i didnt post here . if button yes the program will loop and will loop until the user click no to compute overall what he/she buy .

Comment: The comment about the loop is not about looping until you want to stop computing, its about cleaning up the creation of your elements. As stated though, that was not the main point of my answer, it was merely a suggestion. The main point of my answer was to answer your question and advising you to use ArrayList to solve the problem you are having.

Comment: that is my syntax code sir . i have a program its the same but it is JOptionPane so its easier i used in my JOp a z = all benta[1]-[10];

Comment: so i can easily put addprod = benta[z]; but not the same thing as the Gui because of the labels in whole frame i cant declare like the JOP :c

Comment: Sorry bud, I really wish I can help you more, but I am having problems understanding the specifics of what is required. I hope someone can help you more in depth.

Comment: I guess going back to the original question. You state " i need to set an array for easy way of incrementing it". What are you referring to?

Comment: i see i see but if you run of my program the only problem is the addprod = prod[]; line because i dont know what did i need to pit inside of my prod[here];

Comment: yes to increment because my program is if you buy example product 1 1pcs and if will ask do you want to buy more and if you yes you choose again then let say you choose product 2 1pcs and ask if you want to buy more and if you click no then the product 1 and 2 will add as a whole price with each product name like product 1 1pcs 25php product 2 1psc 25pcs the receipt is 50 . but i am not done with my do while loop to loop that question all i wanna know is on my arrray .

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out putting this into a bigger loop. You could set up a loop and then use generic statements to add Labels and size them instead of adding a different Label object for each one. It would cut about 20 lines of code.

EDIT: By loops I was talking about how to deal with setting bounds and adding to the panel. An example would be something like

```
while(condition)
{
panel.add(new JLabel(information).setBounds(bounds));

}
```

This gets rid of the repetition of having code like:

```
JLabel p1 = new JLabel(info);
JLabel p2 = new JLabel(info2);
...
panel1.add(p1);
panel1.add(p2);
...
p1.setBounds(bounds1);
p2.setBounds(bounds2);
...
```

Comment: where do i need to put that sir ? on my prod ? please edit my work on program to deeply understand

Comment: i cant understand where i am need to put that :3 . sorry i am bad in english

Comment: I edited the code. Look above your block of JLabel stuff. I put a comment line above and below my code to differentiate. And no worries on the English.

Comment: look at in the addprod = benta[]; it is error and also the line you edited its error to me sir .

Comment: @CoderShei My code wasnt supposed to be fully implemented. I put it in comment blocks to explain how to change your code below. You should definitely get some errors if you didn't put in the missing code. You would also have to remove your code that mine was meant to replace. What was the error?

Comment: @CoderShei There is a adding = benta[]; I don't know why that is not working. And can you copy/paste the exact error so I can get a better idea of where in the for loop it is failing?

Comment: ill copy and paste your code sir and i cant de bug the error inside this loop .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47249/discussion-between-alex-johnson-and-codershei)

Comment: click on the link "continue this discussion in chat" in my previous comment. There are not supposed to be extended discussions in the comments.